# Created notification android not been diplayed in the phone

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

Currently developing an android application, and my notifications are not shown in the phone.

I am connecting my phisical phone to android studio, and I see that the method that send notification is been called, but is not displaying any notifications in the phone.

```
private void createNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat)
                .setContentTitle("New match!!!")
                .setContentText("You got a new match!!!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        mNotificationManager.notify(001,builder.build());
    }
```

previously im initializing `mNotoficationManager` as follows:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

any idea on why my phone doesnt display my notification when I get that method call? is been called from a service that I created to change events in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Found this code that works from android 8 onwards.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Tortuga");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("New match on WeRoom")
                .setContentText("You got a new match, you can now chat with someone more!!!")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1001";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.notify(0 /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
```